# Reduce key, value pair based on similarity of their value in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, key-value

I am a beginner in PySpark.

I want to find the pairs of letters with the same numbers in values and then to find out which pair of letters appear more often.

Here is my data

```
data = sc.parallelize([('a', 1), ('b', 4), ('c', 10), ('d', 4), ('e', 4), ('f', 1), ('b', 5), ('d', 5)])
data.collect()
[('a', 1), ('b', 4), ('c', 10), ('d', 4), ('e', 4), ('f', 1), ('b', 5), ('d', 5)]
```

The result I want would look like this:

```
1: a,f
4: b, d
4: b, e
4: d, e
10: c
5: b, d
```

I have tried the following:

```
data1= data.map(lambda y: (y[1], y[0]))
data1.collect()
[(1, 'a'), (4, 'b'), (10, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (1, 'f'), ('b', 5), ('d', 5)]

data1.groupByKey().mapValues(list).collect()
[(10, ['c']), (4, ['b', 'd', 'e']), (1, ['a', 'f']), (5, ['b', 'd'])]
```

As I said I am very new to PySpark and tried to search the command for that but was not successful. Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` with python `itertools.combinations` to get combinations of 2 from the grouped values. Also, prefer using `reduceByKey` rather than `groupByKey`:

```
from itertools import combinations

result = data.map(lambda x: (x[1], [x[0]])) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b) \
    .flatMap(lambda x: [(x[0], p) for p in combinations(x[1], 2 if (len(x[1]) > 1) else 1)])

result.collect()

#[(1, ('a', 'f')), (10, ('c',)), (4, ('b', 'd')), (4, ('b', 'e')), (4, ('d', 'e')), (5, ('b', 'd'))]
```

If you want to get None when tuple has only one element, you can use this:

```
.flatMap(lambda x: [(x[0], p) for p in combinations(x[1] if len(x[1]) > 1 else x[1] + [None], 2)])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, I would like to add None if there is only one value (10, ('c', None) instead of (10, ('c',). How would I change this? I was trying to change the code, but it is not working.

Comment: @user14913431 You can use this `.flatMap(lambda x: [(x[0], p) for p in combinations(x[1] if len(x[1]) > 1 else x[1] + [None], 2)])` instead. Updated my answer.